# Can composition of morphisms in a category be carried out on any subgraph of a commutative diagram, in-place?

Tags: category-theory, math-software, function-and-relation-composition, natural-deduction, diagram-chasing

Here is what the rule looks like to us and how we specify it to the app I'm writing.

I was wondering can you take any *commutative*  diagram $J$ and apply this rule to a subgraph matching $A \xrightarrow{a} B \xrightarrow{b} C$ in place, all the while leaving another commutative diagram.  Or does adding in the hypotenuse sometimes break commutativity of a larger diagram?

If it preserves commutativity, what is a simple proof?

[image: ZoomSpace composition intro rule, example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider any two parallel paths. 
Change every occurance of the new arrow $b\circ a$ to the subpath $a, b$. 
Since the original diagram commutes, the composition of the two changed paths coincide. 
Consequently, the new diagram is commutative, as well.